# Meshlab running slowly

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to generate surface from a point cloud which contains almost 7 000 000 points using Ball pivoting algorithm. It has been running more than 18 hours but only 56% of the process is completed. I am using 2016.12 version of the Meshlab. My computer is a workstation with 64GB ram. Do you think this is normal? Is it possible to speed up this surface generation process?
I am looking forward to hearing from you
Regards